# Is there a pipe operator that will run code before subscription is resolving? ex: http call

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I'm making HTTP calls and want to set a loading indicator before the HTTP call is made. At the moment I'm doing:

```
this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(true)
    this.cop.getunMappedTechnologyDetails().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(false);
      }),
    ).subscribe(
      res => {...}
```

But I would like to set the loadingindicator inside the pipe if possible, so that I can be sure it runs and so that I can easily copy/paste it in front of all my subscriptions. (I've looked in to AOP, but it seems to be unpractical in this particular case)

tap doesn't work because it fetches first and then acts upon the result, but I'm showing it as visual for what I want to have:

```
this.cop.getunMappedTechnologyDetails().pipe(
      tap(() => this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(true)),
      finalize(() => {
        this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(false);
      }),
    ).subscribe(
      res => {...}
```

I might be looking into a generic function too, but for now I need a quick solution where I could paste in these pipes in front of my subscriptions.

EDIT:
I've tried Jan-Niklas Wortmann option with defer, but I get an error on .pipe:

I then tried using it inside the pipe:

```
this.cop.getunMappedSafeDetails().pipe(
      defer(() => {
        this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(true);
        return this.cop.getunMappedSafeDetails();
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(false);
      }),
    ).subscribe(...);
```

But I have error :

```
Argument of type 'Observable<String[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<String[], {}>'.
  Type 'Observable<String[]>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<String[]>): Observable<{}>'.
```

Comment: did you try to use http interceptor for this? http interceptor can intercept all requests and set loading indicator on/off for every http request

Comment: @Ludevik interesting solution, I've tried it but I notice that the http calls don't take so much time, there are other things going on inside the subscription..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write like this:

```
this.cop.getunMappedTechnologyDetails().pipe(
  startWithTap(() => this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(true)),
  finalize(() => this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(false)),
)
```

Whenever you subscribe to above Observable, `startWithTap` will execute whatever you pass instantly and then switch to Original Observable. Lastly, finalize will execute callback when source Observable completes.

And the custom operator for it:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function startWithTap<T>(callback: () => void) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    of({}).pipe(tap(callback), switchMap((o) => source));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `defer` for that purpose.

Code would look like this:

```
defer(() => {
   this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(true));
   return this.cop.getunMappedTechnologyDetails();
}).pipe(finalize(() => {
        this.loadingIndicatorService.setLoadingIndicatorOn(false);
  }),
).subscribe(
  res => {...}
)
```

`defer` is a side-effect that happens when you subscribe to this observable, therefore it's kinda the opposite of `finalize`. But do notice it is every time executed when you subscribe to an observable

Comment: I've tried your proposition, but I can't make it work, see the edit in the question please

Comment: `defer` is a creation operator. Do notice that you return the observable in there. So you can't apply `defer` on the observable but rather you return it inside the function.

You can  see that I return `return this.cop.getunMappedSafeDetails();` at the end of the function inside `defer`

Comment: I understand, but your snippet didn't work, .pipe gave an error unexpected token..

Comment: Just wanted to let any reader know, that this solution works and is the correct one without using any custom observables.